PolarDB archive partition table
We are using PolarDB 8.0.1, we want to archive the old data partition to csv/orc format to save storage space (only store current data in the ibd file). We tried it at table level, and it seems work fine:
Alter table table_name storage_type oss
But the following command does not work, any idea?
Alter table table_name change partition part_name engine = csv
We tried it at table level, and it seems work fine:
Alter table table_name storage_type oss
